# How to show the tag/s product in review order tab in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I'm trying to show next to each single product its tag or tags in the review order table.
This is my code in override review-order.php but doesn't work.
From my review-order.php:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                <td class="product-name">
                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'n&ordm;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    <?php 
                    $terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
                    $term_array = array();
                    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $term_array[] = $term->name;
                        }
                    }

                    if( in_array( 'bird', $term_array ) ) {
                        echo 'Bird';
                    }
                    elseif( in_array( 'dog', $term_array ) ) {
                        echo 'Dog';
                        }
                     else { 
                        echo 'not exists animal';
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
    ?>
</tbody>
```

This return only "not exists animal".
Obviously something wrong! But I can't figure out what.
Better would be work in the custom woocommerce-functions.php I have, but once again I don't know how.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Based on this question and its answers:
[Display Woocommerce Product Category on cart and checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020610/display-woocommerce-product-category-on-cart-and-checkout-page)
watching also the answer with no vote and using a bit of imagination this below is the working code. To complete the test, I added the product category in addition to the tag. I hope it will be helpful to someone.
This is my overwritten order-review.php template now.

```
 <?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 5.2.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Tag', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Category', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'n&ordm;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>                    
                        <?php
                            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
                    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    $product_tag = $term->name;
                                }
                            echo $product_tag ;
                            }               
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>                    
                        <?php
                            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
                    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    $product_cat = $term->name;
                                }
                            echo $product_cat ;
                            }               
                        ?>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just to be clear notice that:

1. I added this code(from cart.php)

   ```
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
   ```
2. and this in the loop

   ```
                    <td>
                    <?php
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
                if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $product_tag = $term->name;
                            }
                        echo $product_tag ;
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <?php
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
                if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $product_cat = $term->name;
                            }
                        echo $product_cat ;
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
   ```

Here it is!