# Display Woocommerce Parent Product Category on cart and checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

I've tried the solution explaned here [Display Woocommerce Product Category on cart and checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020610/display-woocommerce-product-category-on-cart-and-checkout-page)
but this way all categories are displayed, I'm only interested in the parent category.

I used this code in checkout and cart foreach loop:

`echo wc_get_product_category_list( $cart_item['product_id'] );`

For example:
I have these cat and sub cat

```
- MARIA
-- SEDIE
-- TAVOLI
- GIOVANNI
-- SEDIE
-- TAVOLI
```

If I use the code above, I will see the list of selected categories and subcategories; what I would like is to display only the parent categories (MARIA or GIOVANNI)

Thanks for support

Comment: Can you explaing in details so we can help as soon as possible.

Comment: Sure, for example I have these cat and sub cat:

- MARIA
-- SEDIE
-- TAVOLI
- GIOVANNI
-- SEDIE
-- TAVOLI

If I use the code above, I will see the list of selected categories and subcategories; what I would like is to display only the parent categories (MARIA or GIOVANNI)